# Election notification description is not displaying in the global inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

Recently I received a notification about the Travel SE election nomination, I can read the notification description in the **Recent inbox messages**.

> [image: Recent Inbox messages]

But the same notification description is not displaying in the **global inbox** page.

> [image: Global Inbox - Travel SE]

This display issue is not specific to Travel SE, I found the same issue for other Stack Exchange communities.

Screenshot reference for the Stack Overflow election's three phases notifications.

> [image: Global Inbox - Stack Overflow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the election related notification descriptions are displaying in the global inbox.

Adding screenshot from the recent Travel SE election notification:

> [image: Election notice displaying now in Global inbox]